# How do I configure Google Chrome to auto-reload refreshed kerberos tickets?

Tags: google-chrome, kerberos

Current behaviour of Chrome om MacOS is that you have to restart the entire browser if your kerberos ticket expired and was renewed.

It seems that Chrome is using the kerberos ticket that was existing at the moment Chrome started but if in meanwhile this one expired and was renewed you have to restart the browser.

Comment: I raised a bug at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=671959 -- currently is private but I asked the team to make it public so others will be able to vote/comment on it.